# Matching the wrong delimiter

Tags: rust

This is my code:

```
fn main() {
    let list = [3,1,-3,-9,-17];    
    let mut dif: [i32; 2] = [0, 0];
    let mut squares: [usize; 2] = [0, 0];
    let base: i32 = 2;
    
    for i in 1..3 {
        dif[i-1] = list[i] - list[i - 1];
    }
    let dif2 = dif[1] - dif[0];

    for i in 1..3 {
        squares[i-1] = base.pow(((dif2 as usize)/2*i), 1024));
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
  --> src/main.rs:15:1
   |
1  | fn main() {
   |           - this opening brace...
...
14 |     }
   |     - ...matches this closing brace
15 | }
   | ^ unexpected closing delimiter
```

But, the `{` on 1 should match the `}` at line 15.

I'm new to rust, so sorry if the solution is obvious and I just haven't realized it.

Comment: it doesn't really fit with the error message you're receiving, but you have an additional unpaired `)` on line 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line No 13 you have an extra closing `)`:

```
squares[i-1] = base.pow(((dif2 as usize)/2*i), 1024));
```

See the *whole* error message (not just the first lines, which, admittedly, can be misleading):

```
error: unexpected closing delimiter: `}`
  --> src/main.rs:15:1
   |
1  | fn main() {
   |           - this opening brace...
...
14 |     }
   |     - ...matches this closing brace
15 | }
   | ^ unexpected closing delimiter

error: mismatched closing delimiter: `)`
  --> src/main.rs:12:19
   |
12 |     for i in 1..3 {
   |                   ^ unclosed delimiter
13 |         squares[i-1] = base.pow(((dif2 as usize)/2*i), 1024));
   |                                                             ^ mismatched closing delimiter
```